# setInterval does not take the state of the hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I call an api every x time with setInterval I must pass some parameters to the api to get the data, my parameters are state hooks, the problem is that when I update a state hook for example "ChoiceIpGroup" the setinterval always takes the initial value and not the update of the state of the hook. What could be happening ?

```
useEffect(() => {
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            //getKPIMetricas(setdata, dataFilter)
            getMetricsInGroups(dataFilter, setDataKPisGroups, choiceIpGroup)
        }, 4000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);
```

I update the hook states from the front, when I change the hook state it works, but when the setinterval is updated the hook state is updated to the initial parameter. what is an empty array

`const [choiceIpGroup, setChoiceIpGroup] = useState([])`

and when updating the hook it would look like this:

```
const [choiceIpGroup, setChoiceIpGroup] = useState([ "0", "1" ])
```

but when setinterval() acts it doesn't take the update of the hook's state, only the initial state.

Comment: Exactly how are those variables declared, and where (in relation to the posted code)?

Comment: only the choiceipgroup variable matters here

Comment: How can you be sure of that if you posted the question here in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

setInterval is a method that calls a function or runs some code after specific intervals of time, as specified through the second parameter. For example, the code below schedules an interval to print the phrase: “Interval triggered” every second to the console until it is cleared. setInterval(() => { console.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can’t see that your answer is helpful at all. It gives a definition of setinterval which you have copied from elsewhere but you don’t explain why this solves the problem posed in the question. It’s good to try to answer questions, but with more in depth thought and explanation.